# How to create a transparent background to a flash animation?

Tags: flash-cs4

I want to create a transparent background to my flash animation and save it in GIF format.
please help me..

Answer (score 2):

This page explains the settings you need to publish a transparent GIF:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7bc8a.html

The main relevant steps are:

1. Select File > Publish Settings, click Formats, and select GIF Image.
2. Select "Transparent" for the "Transparent" option.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to make it work.

1. Publish settings-> Play : Animate (Continuous loop)
2. Transparent : Transparent

   3. Uncheck Smooth
   4. Click Publish.